# Reusing view controllers and its ivars, scrollviews, tableview

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, memory-management

Smart people,

General question as the code is just too much to past in here.  I understand I will get general answers.  I am just hoping to get a few more ideas of where to look for a solution.  Here is my set up:

```
OpenGL view - "game view"
UIView - "city view"
ScrollView "city menu"
The scrollview uses 6 view controllers.
One viewController in scroll contains a tableView
```

When a "player" enters a "city" the scroll view appears and displays all the view controllers and viola everything works great.

Problem is when the "player" leaves the "city" and goes to the next one, the view controllers still contain the information from the last "city".

This is despite of the following:

- The array containing all of the view controllers for the scroll view is set to nil when the "player" leaves the "city".
- That same array is set to a newly allocated array when the "player" enters a new "city".
- The ivars in the view controllers are set to nil when its viewWillDisappear.
- The ivars in the view controllers are set to a new array during its init.
- The initializing of the view controller all of the ivars are reinitialized during their init ( I have also tried in the viewWillAppear) as well.
- The tableView is calling using arrays (the ivars spoken of earlier).

I appreciate any and all advise.

E

- The reason this is driving me so nuts, is I am clearly assigning my array with the view controllers to nil.  All of those objects should be released.  zilch.

Solved:  It seems that the retain count of one of my data arrays is being reduced arbitrarily somewhere.  My only guess is that in the tableView transition somewhere its getting reduced.  Thanks for the view.

Comment: Hey since you solved this. Try adding your solution as an answer and marking it as the answer that worked for you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: It seems that the retain count of one of my data arrays is being reduced arbitrarily somewhere. My only guess is that in the tableView transition somewhere its getting reduced.